# Android doesn't have appropriate encoding

Tags: android, browser, httpservice

I have httpservice on android device. It forms response as html page to some browser. So it works fine but if I use other languages (for example Russian), server returns unreadable text instead of Russian symbols. I know that default encoding on Android is UTF-8. I've tried every encoding available on the Android (For example windows-1251, Big5(Chinese), UTF-16 and so on) but it returned wrong result at all. Here is some code which show you what I've tried to do:

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {

 HttpEntity entity = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {
            public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {

                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "windows-1251");
                String resp = "<html><body>Hello Привет</body></html>";
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(resp, "windows-1251");
                se.writeTo(outstream);
                //writer.write(resp);
                //writer.flush();
            }
        });
    response.setHeader("Context-Type", "text/html");                    
    response.setEntity(entity);
}
```

So in browser I see next:

```
Hello ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚
```

What do I wrong? Please, answer me.
I'll appreciate for any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the server is not supporting utf-8 correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using [java.text.Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) or add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />` to your response.

Besides, I'd recommend you not to hardcode strings, but put them to resources and load them with [`Resources.getString(resId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int%29) instead - thus you would have potentially less problems with encodings.